# TFS Migration Risks

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I would like to create a new installation of TFS 2013 on a new server.

I made my research and learnt that the migration process as it is described on this link below carries some risks:

**TFS Migration Manual:** 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

**Risks:**

http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2014/04/12/tfs-upgrade-nightmares/

I have a plan to avoid using the TFS Migration manual above, instead; I would instead check all of my projects out (about 20) and then re-create them on the new TFS and check them in again.

However, we have work-items, users, workspaces and other agile information which I have created for my projects, and which I still require to be on the new installation.

I was wondering whether the following works (again without risks and hassle, as time is scarce):

*Back up the TFS Databases from the old installation, and restore them into the new installation or simply import the data from old to new using SQL Server's Data Import Tool.*

I am particularly referring to these databases, which TFS has:

- Tfs_Configuration; Tfs_DefaultCollection; Tfs_Warehouse.

I found these databases on the SQL Server instance which TFS uses.

Also, this approach works easier without having to obstruct the team, as the Data Base Resotation can occur after hours..

Now, will this plan work?

Comment: Better you use tfs data migration tools to bring whatever you need out of workitems, testassets. That way it would be much more simpler and risk free. It will allow you to select what you want to bring over to new instance. Let me know if you need further help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your plan will not work and will leave your TFS in an unsupported state.

You need to follow a combination of the Upgrade and "changing environment" workflow.

1) Restore all TFS databases (tfs_*) to tye new environment

2) Install TFS 2015

3) Configure and select Upgrade Wizard - when running make sure you have all the new server names

4) (optional) ChangeServerID - if this is a practice run you should then immediately:

4.1) I unconfigure the application tier with "tfsconfig exe setup /uninstall:all"

4.2) run the ChangeServerID command

4.3) reconfigure  tfs and run the "app tier only" wizard

Simples....

Note: You need to change the server ID if this is a test/practice instance as each server gets a unique ID. When clients first connect to the new server they will "upgrade/migrate" the users data across. You don't want that happening for a trial...so change the ID...

WARNING: If you manipulate the data in the TFS server in any way that is not done by the TFS Product Team tools you will turn your instance to crap. Do not ever edit, or cause to edit, the data in the operational store.

Comment: Note: You can put any version where I put 2015, but why you would install anything but the latest supported version is beyond me.